# How to edit the font color of the VCS Commit dialog window

Tags: pycharm

I upgraded to Pycharm40 from Pycharm34 and imported my old settings.

However, when I go to commit changes to version control, the "commit message" text input is white font on a white background.

Picture of highlighted text:

[image]

This makes adding a message difficult. I spent a few hours searching online and poking around my /users/pycharm/config files but without complete success.

If I change the "default text" foreground color (Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General) I can see that changes the "Commit message" window but it also changes everything else.

Does anyone know how to specifically change the Commit Dialog's commit message font color? Either foreground or background color.

Comment: I have this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem, too.  I was able to get around it by resetting the UI Theme (Appearance & Behavior > Appearance > Theme) several time.  After resetting the theme, the text appeared in the "commit message" window.